# why does my class schema looks broken in fastAPi and swagger?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I have fastAPI application. Using python 3.9

I have the following module

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class IdentificationRequest(BaseModel):

    def __init__(self, request_id):
        super().__init__()

        self.request_id = request_id
```

and my endpoint looks like

```
@router.post("/", response_model=xyz)
def decide(request: IdentificationRequest):
```

when I look at my schema (in the docs page), the schema looks broken

```
IdentificationRequest{
}
```

what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need this

```
class IdentificationRequest(BaseModel):
    request_id: str
```

Comment: I had not tried that version, I did try     request_id: str = ""     which did not work either.

Comment: Don't override `__init__` method,  Write the field in the class as a class attribute